# How to remove first element of mysql_query and get all the rest?

Tags: php, mysql

Before I begin, I will say that I'm stuck in old mysql api for the moment.

I have:

```
mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 3");
```

however, I need to get the 3 elements after the first element from the posts table. Is there any way of doing that inside mysql_query function?

Comment: `LIMIT 1, 3` I think. Edit: seeing the upvotes on this, is "it". ;-) *There you go Saul*. (solved)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions]....ooops, just remembered you cannot make that change righjt now.

Comment: LIMIT 1,3 => where 1 is the starting index and 3 is number of values to be returned.

Comment: what about OFFSET?

Comment: To think I could have cashed in big time! *woohoo!!!* hahahaha. Too funny.

Comment: Awesome, it solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Before we answer, get yourself unstuck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use numerical offsets:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 1, 3
```

See [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

```
SELECT
...
LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}
```

Comment: [*niah niah...I answered first lol!!!*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119426/how-to-remove-first-element-of-mysql-query-and-get-all-the-rest#comment61779869_37119426) just joking ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are right and I up-voted your comment. But to be honest - I didn't saw your comment before answering.